# nginx: reverse proxy doesn't work

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have two websites like:

- http://example.com
- http://example.com:8080/mybackendapp

I want to set up a reverse proxy like:

http://example.com/mybackendapp -> http://example.com:8080/mybackendapp
http://example.com/mybackendapp/ -> http://example.com:8080/mybackendapp
http://example.com/mybackendapp/all_sub_url -> http://example.com:8080/mybackendapp

In the nginx.conf file, i set the config like :

```
location /mybackendapp/ {
    resolver 127.0.0.1;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/mybackendapp;
}
```

After modifying the file, i have restarted `nginx` service. But the reverse proxy don't work. When i try to open exemple.com/mybackendapp in browser. I have 404 error.

Could you please help me solve this problem?

Comment: Dude, it took me a whoa 5 minutes to realize that you meant ***reverse** proxy* by typing *reserve proxy* everywhere. Type carefully when posting on Stack Overflow next time, ***please***.

Comment: Thank you very much for the correction. I will take care of my typing the next time.